# Syntax for SOAP through Powershell

Tags: xml, web-services, powershell, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to order SSL Certificates through Globalsign's API with Powershell, using the PVOrder method.  URL is https://test-gcc.globalsign.com/kb/ws/v1/ManagedSSLService?wsdl and they have documentation here https://downloads.globalsign.com/acton/attachment/2674/f-092e/1/-/-/-/-/globalsign-mssl-api-user-guide-v2.3.pdf

The Powershell I'm using is very simple:

```
$URI = "https://test-gcc.globalsign.com/kb/ws/v1/ManagedSSLService?wsdl"
$result = (iwr $URI –infile "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\script_other\pvorder_soap.xml" –contentType "text/xml" –method POST)
```

And the XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:complexType name="PVOrder">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Request" type="tns:BmV1PvOrderRequest"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="BmV1PvOrderRequest">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="OrderRequestHeader" type="tns:OrderRequestHeader"/>
<xs:element name="OrderRequestParameter" type="tns:OrderRequestParameter"/>
<xs:element name="MSSLProfileID" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="MSSLDomainID" type="xs:string"/>
...
</xs:complexType>
```

However I'm running into difficulty trying to figure out where the parameters are supposed to be defined.  The XML design on most of the tutorials I've found looks different from the XML here.  Some searching on google lead me to try putting the parameters at the end of the xml but before the  which I tried so it looks like below, but the response didn't change at all.

```
...
<MSSLDomainID>test.com</MSSLDomainID>
</xs:complexType>
```

Any ideas on what I should be doing here?  I have a decent amount of experience with Powershell but none with SOAP and none of the tutorials I've read seemed to have an answer for this.

Comment: WSDL describes what the xml should look like. what your posting looks like WSDL. it should be XML. eg. <Request>
<BmV1PvOrdertHeader> .... <MSSLDomainID>test.com</MSSLDomainID>  ...</BmV1PvOrdertHeader></Request>

Comment: Why don't you just create a WebServicesProxy with the New-WebServiceProxy cmdlet? This cmdlet is build to handle SOAP based APIs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not post WSDL. this describes what the XML is supposed to look like.

What you really need an example of what an XML should be & then you can just plug your variables into it.  The documentation you've got describes the format of the order. doesn't actually have an example.  I did a quick search, but could not find one for your specific need.  technically with the WSDL you should be able to construct it.

This [GlobalSign doco](https://www.globalsign.com/files/6014/7223/7125/globalsign-ssl-api-user-guide.pdf) shows some examples of actual XML you post but is not for your specific API.

**UPDATE:**  Found a service which analyzes WSDL and gives you example XML you can work with.  Take a look at https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/

1. Copy/paste just [WSDL from API](https://test-gcc.globalsign.com/kb/ws/v1/ManagedSSLService?wsdl) in a a text file
2. Upload [here](https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/upload/doUploadWsdl)
3. Click on Operation->EVOrder
4. Example XML you can work with.  this is what you can POST into your code.

Comment: Powershell has a built in cmdlet to handle WSDL (New-WebServicesProxy).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the website link, that's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of invoke web request use the utility built into Powershell called [New-WebServiceProxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-webserviceproxy?view=powershell-5.1) .   Once you've done that you'll be able to see the methods and properties exposed by the webservice.

```
$Proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri https://test-gcc.globalsign.com/kb/ws/v1/ManagedSSLService?wsdl
$Proxy | get-member 
Name                                 MemberType Definition                                                                                                                                                                               
----                                 ---------- ----------                                                                                                                                                                               
AddDomainToProfileCompleted          Event      Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1b_ws_v1_ManagedSSLService_wsdl.AddDomainToProfileCompletedEventHandler AddDomainToProfileCompleted...
AddMSSLDomainCompleted               Event      Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1b_ws_v1_ManagedSSLService_wsdl.AddMSSLDomainCompletedEventHandler AddMSSLDomainCompleted(System.Ob...
AddMSSLProfileCompleted              Event      Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1b_ws_v1_ManagedSSLService_wsdl.AddMSSLProfileCompletedEventHandler AddMSSLProfileCompleted(System....
ChangeSubjectAltNameCompleted        Event      Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewWebserviceProxy.AutogeneratedTypes.WebServiceProxy1b_ws_v1_ManagedSSLService_wsdl.ChangeSubjectAltNameCompletedEventHandler ChangeSubjectAltNameCompl...
Disposed                             Event      System.EventHandler
```

Using this proxy I was able to get the type from it in this means:

```
 $Proxy = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri https://test-gcc.globalsign.com/kb/ws/v1/ManagedSSLService?wsdl -namespace globalsign -Class managed
 $proxyType = $proxy.gettype().Namespace
 $bmv1pvOrderRequest = New-Object("$proxyType.BmV1PvOrderRequest")
PS:\> $bmv1pvOrderRequest


OrderRequestHeader    : 
OrderRequestParameter : 
MSSLProfileID         : 
MSSLDomainID          : 
SubID                 : 
PVSealInfo            : 
ContactInfo           : 
SANEntries            : 
Extensions            :
```

I chose to try and fill in contactinfo its type is Contactinfo so you have to create an object of that type and fill in the elements:

```
$C = new-object ("$proxyType.contactinfo")
$C.FirstName = 'thom'
$c.lastname = 'schumacher'
$c
FirstName LastName   Phone Email
--------- --------   ----- -----
thom      schumacher
```

Next you'll need to go through each item in the $bmv1pvOrderRequest and proxy in a new one of each of the types as necessary and then send the request to the Webservice.

```
$o = new-object ("$proxyType.orderRequestHeader")
$o
AuthToken
---------
PS:\> $p = new-object ("$proxyType.orderRequestParameter")

PS:\> $p


ProductCode          : 
BaseOption           : 
OrderKind            : 
Licenses             : 
Options              : 
ValidityPeriod       : 
CSR                  : 
RenewalTargetOrderID : 
TargetCERT           : 
SpecialInstructions  : 
Coupon               : 
Campaign             : 

$bmv1pvOrderRequest.OrderRequestHeader = $o
$bmv1pvOrderRequest.OrderRequestParameter = $p
$bmv1pvOrderRequest.ContactInfo = $c
```

Comment: Don't forget the -NameSpace parameter when creating the proxy so you can access the classes the WSDL endpoint exposes in a normal fashion.

Comment: I agree that has bitten me before.. I generally use -namespace and -class so that I know exactly what I've called them... Instead of the autogenerated class that the module makes.

Comment: I did use new-webserviceproxy and gm to find the list of methods, that's part of how I knew PVOrder was the method I needed, but that doesn't answer my initial question of how to figure out the XML, unless there's some way to do that with new-webserviceproxy.

Comment: @bluegrey : what is there to find out exactly? New-WebServiceProxy will create all the required .NET classes for you based on the XML from the WDSL : basicly you need no to minimal information from the XML because of that.